How put sessions in Laravel 11 api routes?
How are you guys?
In Laravel 11 how many do I try to put sessions for the shop's cart by Api routes, the sessions don't store!
Do you Have a solution for it?
even in Laravel 11 kernel.php removed!
now for the cart's session should I use a route in web.php?

You can use the session() helper functions
On the blade:

@if(session('cart'))
@endif

On the controller:

session()->get('key');


session()->put('key');


but, I would like to store my cart by Api but in Laravel 11 I can't!

By default, your application's routes are configured and loaded by the bootstrap/app.php file:
<?php
 
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
 
return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )->create();

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
 
->withRouting(
    commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
    using: function () {
        Route::middleware('api')
            ->prefix('api')
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
 
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    },
)

